# JSF and/or PrimeFaces stylesheets and scripts go to /Project/javax.faces.resource location instead of ./javax.faces.resource

Tags: jsf, nginx, primefaces

I made "myproject.com" (for example) to be as "http://localhost:8080/MyProject/" using Nginx's proxy_pass option. All works ok, but PrimeFaces stylesheets and scripts tries to go to "/MyProject/file", what isn't good because of proxing to nonexistent "http://localhost:8080/MyProject/MyProject/file".
How can I made PF use ./file instead of /MyProject/file? Making Nginx's location block or link to MyProject folder is bad variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I have the strong impression that this problem really needs to be solved in the Ngnix proxy side, I'll explain how you could "workaround" it from the JSF side on.

JSF resources are represented by the [`Resource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html) class wherein the [`getRequestPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html#getRequestPath%28%29) method is responsible for returning the resource URL. You could create a custom `Resource` implementation wherein the `getRequestPath()` is implemented/overridden accordingly.

```
public class MyResource extends ResourceWrapper {

    private Resource wrapped;

    public MyResource(Resource wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestPath() {
        String contextPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
        return "." + wrapped.getRequestPath().substring(contextPath.length());
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

Now, to override the default JSF `Resource` by this custom implementation, you need to create a custom [`ResourceHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) implementation wherein you return the custom `Resource` implementation instead in the [`createResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#createResource%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

```
public class MyResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    private ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public MyResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        return new MyResource(wrapped.createResource(resourceName, libraryName));
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

Finally, to get it to run, register it as `<resource-handler>` in the `faces-config.xml`.

```xml
<application>
    <resource-handler>com.example.MyResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: So you recommend to make something like this (nginx):
location /MyProject {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/MyProject/;
}
? Thanks.

Comment: I don't do Ngnix, so I can't go in its details. Since you asked this question here at stackoverflow.com (a QA site for programmers) instead of at serverfault.com (a QA site for serveradmins), I understood that you were looking for a programmatic solution/workaround.

Answer (score 1):

i am a little late with this answer, but i had the same problem and tried to do it the 'nginx' way.

So maybe this helps others out also.

you can define a second location in your nginx configuration (this surely depends on your specific configuration) which will match for a specific rule for every traffic matching the pattern for the location.

your first location in the nginx server config will look somewhat similar to this:

```
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/MyProject$request_uri;
    }
```

then you just need to add a second location for your resources, which will tell nginx to not add the MyProject in the rewrite for resources which match to the specific location pattern, e.g.:

```
    location /MyProject {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080$request_uri;
    }
```

Note that the proxy_pass has changed for '/MyProject/javax.faces.resource'. Your js, images and css should now be delivered correctly again.

More about locations can be found in the nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).